# How to enable load on scroll in django-endless-pagination?

Tags: django, infinite-scroll, django-endless-pagination

I have followed the documentation as best as I can. But I can't pin point the mistake here.

My view looks like this.

```py
class ProductListView(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxListView):
     model = Product
     paginate_by = 12
     template_name = 'products_list.html'
     page_template = 'products_page.html'
```

The template

```html
 <div class="row">
     <ul id="products_list" class="thumbnails endless_page_template">
     {% include page_template %}
     </ul>
 </div>
```

The page template

```html
{% load endless %}
 {% paginate 8 products_list %}
 {% for product in products_list %}
     <li class="span3">
         .
         .
         .
         <!-- each item html -->

     </li>
 {% endfor %}
 {% show_more %}
```

And this is what I put inside script tags on the same page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $.endlessPaginate({
              paginateOnScroll: true,
              paginateOnScrollMargin: 20,                                 
         });
});
```

I looked at this question - [django-endless-pagination doesn't seem to be using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778105/django-endless-pagination-doesnt-seem-to-be-using-ajax) but didn't find any solutions there. I don't see any network call being made in the console when I reach the end of the scroll. The page loads with a `show_more` link at the end. When `show_more` link is clicked, it's loading the next page of items via ajax but this doesn't happen automatically as it should be when we set `paginateOnScroll:true`.

Comment: Have you customized in any way the content of the show_more template? The link must have a endless_more class. Also, you might want the remove the comma after 20

Comment: Yeah it has that class. I haven't customized it in any way.

Comment: I don't think that comma matters. Even then, I removed it and checked. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tinkering with endless_pagination.js, I found a fix. It works for me. Submitted a pull request here - https://github.com/frankban/django-endless-pagination/pull/52

Comment: What is the issue you are facing @KarimSonbol ? Have you made sure you 're using the right jquery version that this app uses?

Comment: Same as the issue you described. Nothing happens when scrolling, and "more" link appears at the end of the page. I'm using the latest version of Jquery, the app requires using a version >= 1.7

Comment: have you used the changes made in the pull-request?